# I want to convert an enum type variable to long type in java

Tags: java

I have enum like this:

```
enum E{
    a,
    b
};

E enum1;
```

I want to assign a to long value like this:

```
long p =a;
```

How can I do this? It is giving error saying `can't convert enum type to long`.

Comment: That's because the compiler is right. You can't convert `Enum` to `long`.

Comment: You can try `long p = E.a.ordinal();`

Comment: @anonymous That would depend on what the poster was originally trying to do...

Comment: OP, what is the purpose of getting the enum integer value?

Comment: `long p = enum` is an attempt at implicit casting. Implicit casting is only allowed when the value (in this case, the enum) extends or comes from the heirarchy of the type defined for your variable (long p). You would need some parsing mechinism to achieve such a thing, which doesn't exist for `enum -> long`, as far as I know. James Massey's answer seems like the best approach: have a `long` variable in your enum. That way, you can have a reference to the number you want in your enum. With knowing the limitations now, if you told us your goal, it would be easier to answer

Comment: Thanks. Error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Write a method in your enum call getLong() and return the Long variable that you want from there. You would call `long foo = enum1.getLong()`.

You will have to modify your enum though.

```
public enum foo
    enum1(longfoo) //longfoo is the long number you want to return from enum1.

    private foo(Long longfoo){
        this.longfoo = longfoo;
    }

    private Long longfoo;

    public Long getLong(){
         return longfoo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require a private constructor and variable to be defined for each enum?

Comment: asking both you and OP :P

Answer (score 0):

Enums have a expose a member ordinal, you can use that.
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)

Comment: While that does make the poster's code valid, it might not be what the poster intended...

Comment: I know it's very tempting, but I strongly discourage using `ordinal`, it's enormously prone to bugs. Imagine someone else putting a new entry to the enum, somewhere in between, and everything stops working just because of this little thing. While you can add a comment: "Put new entries at the end!", it's considered a bad design if you have to maintain a proper order of entries. It's better to have a dedicated field in the enum and meaningful accessor for it: `getId()` or `getNumericValue()`, looks better than plain `ordinal()`, right? Javadoc also suggests avoiding it on the daily basis.